# SQL select records using id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called Entertainment. The columns in Entertainment include PrimaryKeys from different tables

The columns in Entertainment are:

```
EntertainmentID|AgentID|GenreID
```

I have another table Named "Band" it is one of the subgroups from Entertainment ( the other one isn't necessary)

I want a query that outputs: The Agents details & The Band Name where the Genre = rock

I'm not sure how to do this

The Columns in Agent are

```
AgentID|AgentName|AgentMobile
```

The columns in Genre are

```
GenreID|GenreName
```

The columns in Band are

```
EntertainmentID|BandName
```

Here is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT Concat(a.AgentFName,' ', a.AgentLName) AS 'Agent Name', a.AgentMobile, a.AgentEmail, b.BandName
FROM Agent a 
Join Band b on a.AgentID = b.EntertainmentID
WHERE Genre IN
(SELECT GenreName
FROM Genre
WHERE Genre='rock');
```

I got an error message that said GenreName is an unknown column

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You need to JOIN your Genre table to your query and you can remove the inner query select

Comment: from what I see the last line checks Genre = 'rock', whereas there is no Column named Genre in the table schema you have shared.

Comment: typo, I've edited that now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT Concat(a.AgentFName,' ', a.AgentLName) AS 'Agent Name', a.AgentMobile, a.AgentEmail, b.BandName
FROM Agent a
--Join Entertainment on Agent AS Entertainment holds a foreign key to Agent
JOIN Entertainment e on e.AgentId = a.AgentId 
--Join Band on Entertainment as Band holds a foreign key to Entertainment
Join Band b on b.EntertainmentId = e.EntertainmentId
--Finally join Genre on Entertainment as Entertainment holds a foreign key to Genre
JOIN Genre g on g.GenreId = e.GenreId
WHERE g.GenreName = 'rock' --Filter down to only rows where GenreName is 'rock
```

Comment: @Toms No problem. Glad to help, I think this is the first time I've had an accepted answer which has a vote count of -1, LOL

Comment: haha! happy I was able to bless you with your first accepted answer

Comment: @RyanWilson I SHALL FIX THAT

Comment: @RJ7 Thank you.